# Binding ContextMenu to Datagrid Columns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to bind `DataGrid` column header to its own `ContextMenu` like this:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="AllLogs">
     <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
         <ContextMenu>
              <MenuItem Header="Show/Hide Columns" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=AllLogs, Path=Columns}">
                    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"></TextBlock>
                         </DataTemplate>
                    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
              </MenuItem>
           </ContextMenu>
       </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
   </DataGrid>
```

Its always sends the following error in output:

> Cannot find source for binding with reference
>   'ElementName=AllLogs'. BindingExpression:Path=Columns;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property
>   is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

---

**EDIT: Binding with a `ComboBox` works as expected**

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=AllLogs, Path=Columns}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <CheckBox Content="{Binding Header}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
         </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `ContextMenu` didn't work but `ComboBox` did is that `ContextMenu` is a `Popup`, that means it's not part of `DataGrid`'s visual tree, so `ElementName` would not work as `ComboBox` did. In fact, @user1672994 was vary close to the answer.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="AllLogs">
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Show/Hide Columns" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding PlacementTarget.Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}">
                <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should set first the `DataContext` of `ContextMenu` so that ItemsSource bind to Menu Item can inherit the same DataContext.

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<MenuItem Header="Show/Hide Columns" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Columns}">
    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"></TextBlock>
         </DataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem/misunderstanding is that `ContextMenu` isn't a part of a visual tree.

So `ContextMenu.PlacementTarget` is your "connection" to the UIElement, which is in the visual tree, therefore you have to go via `PlacementTarget` to access the elements from visual tree.

MSDN about `PlacementTarget`:

> When the ContextMenu is assigned to the FrameworkElement.ContextMenu
>   or FrameworkContentElement.ContextMenu property, the
>   ContextMenuService changes this value of this property to the owning
>   FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement when the ContextMenu opens

In answer below you don't have to traverse searching an ancestor type, but do use an UIElement as `DataContext` for `ContextMenu`:

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <MenuItem Header="Show/Hide Columns" ItemsSource="{Binding Columns}">
            <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the RadGrivView control per say, but the error means that it cannot find an IEnumerable property called "Columns" on your element. Are you sure it is a publicly accessible collection for the control?

Comment: RadGridView is a control from telerik, which is derived from DataGrid. and yes it has publicly accessible getter and a private setter !

Answer (score 0):

ElementName uses VisualTree to find out desired element, it its not part of the current visual tree - up or down as it is with context menu you will get exception.

You could use Binding Source={x:Reference AllLogs} that does not use VisualTree, but unfortunately in your use case you would get exception of circular reference if you use it directly without style.

What you need to use is RelativeSource binding.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="headerMenu">
        <ContextMenu.Items>
            <MenuItem
                Header="Show/Hide Columns"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}">
                <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu.Items>
    </ContextMenu>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource headerMenu}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="AllLogs">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

This would work as well - with Reference:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="headerMenu">
        <ContextMenu.Items>
            <MenuItem
                Header="Show/Hide Columns"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference AllLogs}, Path=Columns}">
                <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu.Items>
    </ContextMenu>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource headerMenu}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="AllLogs">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```